# Using multiple fields in django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have a class where I declare 20 instances of 2 fields.
`models.py`

```
class Genre(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Rock")
   genre_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/",default="1992/08/92")

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Genrevids(models.Model):
   genrename = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
   vid_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Z7JgY9zezj4")
   vid_2 = models.CharField(max_length=300,default="Z7JgY9zezd8")

   def __str__(self):
      return self.vid1
```

`views.py`

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Genrevids
extra = 20

class GenreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = [
    ('The Genre',               {'fields': ['genre_name']}),
    ('Image', {'fields': ['genre_img']}),
]
inlines = [ItemInline]
```

What this does is, it allows me to add 20 instances of `vid_1` and `vid_2`. I want to know if there is a way of adding 20 instances of `vid_1` and 10 instances of `vid_2`

Comment: You are not adding "instances of" vid_1 and/or vid_2, you are adding instances of `Genrevids`.  `vid_1` and `vid_2` are *fields* in `Genrevids`, not models on their own.

Comment: So is there a way to add different instances of `vid_1` and `vid_2` while part of the same model class?

Comment: Err... Please re-read my previous comment. There's **no** such thing as "an instance of vid_1", period. An instance of `Genrevids` has a `vid_1` and a `vid_2` *attributes*, but these attributes don't exist outside `Genrevids`. At the database level, you have a `genrevids` *table* with `vid_1` and `vid_2` *fields*, not 'vid_1' and 'vid_2' tables.